Ignoring invalid geometry in QGIS modeler
I'm using QGIS Modeler to create a custom tool. One of the steps involves using the "Join Attributes by Location" algorithm, but my layers have too many invalid geometries, which prevents it from running.
In the toolbox, I can easily choose to ignore invalid geometries (as shown in the screenshot), but how can I do this in QGIS Modeler?


Can you fix them as a part of your model?

If you set it in the general processing options, the ignore invalid geometriesoption will also take effect when you run the model:

